# What makes the geodesic locally special?

Tags: differential-geometry

A geodesic is a special kind of curve which is related to the local geometry of a surface. If we look at the sphere for instance it is the great circles.

But what makes the geodesic locally? If we look at the north pole then there is a tangentplane with all possible directions, all of which has a geodesic emerging from it.

But there is only one geodesic emerging locally. What makes this geodesic different from the others? I think it might have to do with the connections. Is this the case?

Comment: What do you mean only one geodesic? As you just said, there is one per direction in the tangent space

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen But only one per tanget. It "turns" only in one way

Comment: It is special since it satisfies an ODE. So the initial point and the initial velocity will determine the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to consider surfaces embedded in 3-space, then there's a relatively easy answer (which generalizes easily to curves on $k$-manifolds embedded in $\Bbb R^{k+1}$). Here goes:

The geodesic curve, which I'll call 
$$
t \mapsto c(t),$$
is a curve on the surface, but also a curve in 3-space. We can for each $t$ compute the tangent vector $c'(t)$. The first thing about a geodesic path is that the tangent vector has constant length, so that's one "special thing" about a geodesic curve. Let's call that tangent $T(t)$, so that 
$$
T(t) = c'(t) \\
\| T(t) \| = a
$$
for some nonzero constant $a$. By taking the derivative of this tangent vector, we get a normal vector $N(t)$: 
$$
N(t) = T'(t).
$$

(Side note: if you know about Frenet frames, the $T$ and $N$ I've defined here are just like those in the Frenet frame, except that I have not made them unit length.)

Because $T$ has constant length, the vector $N(t)$ is perpendicular to $T(t)$.

So far, I've said nothing about the surface, and it's time to remedy that.

At the point $c(t)$, there's *also* the unit normal vector to the *surface*, which I'm going to call $n(c(t))$.

Let's make this concrete with a very simple example: the surface $S$ is the $xy$-plane; the curve $c$ is given by
$$
c(t) = (2 \cos t, 2\sin t, 0).
$$
In this case, the tangent vector is 
$$
T(t) = (-2 \sin t, 2 \cos t, 0)
$$
and has length $a = 2$, regardless of the value of $t$, so it has the first "special property". The curve-normal is 
$$
N(t) = (-2\cos t, -2 \sin t, 0)
$$

What about the *surface* normal? Well, regardless of the point, the surface normal is 
$$
n(x, y, 0) = (0, 0, 1).
$$
(OK, it could also be $(0,0,-1)$; the sign will soon turn out not to matter).

In this particular example, where $c$ is definitely **not** a geodesic (the geodesics in the $xy$-plane are exactly the constant-speed curves that traverse straight lines in the plane!), we see that the curve-normal $N(t)$ and the surface normal $n(c(t))$ point in very different directions.

The second "special property" of geodesics is that for every $t$, the vectors $N(t)$ and $n(c(t))$ point in the same direction, or, more explicitly, that there's a number $u(t)$ such that 
$$
N(t) = u(t) n(c(t)).
$$

(It's quite possible that $u$ is negative or zero!)

Those two properties -- constant speed, and curve-normal is a multiple of surface-normal -- characterize geodesics on surfaces in 3-space. You might want to look at parameterized lines of latitude on a sphere to see that the only one that's a geodesic, by this reasoning, is the equator (which is a great circle).

**Practical matters**
Now I've been a tiny bit sloppy in that last paragraph, because I was really assuming that you'd parameterize the line-of-latitude with a constant-speed curve. But maybe you'd like to just consider some path 
$$
t \mapsto e(t)
$$
and ask "is the image of the path $e$, a curve in my surface, also the image of a geodesic path?" [Here I'm using "path" to mean "function from the reals to the surface", while the image of the path is just a point-set on the surface. For instance, $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t, 0)$ is a path on the sphere; the image of that path is the point-set we call "the equator"]. That let's you then informally ask things like "is the equator a geodesic?", which really means "is there a constant speed path whose image is the equator, and which has the "curve-normal-parallel-to-surface-normal" property?" If the answer is "yes", you may not care about the actual constant-speed path -- you might be happy with *any* path that traverses the same curve.

So let's ask the following question:

> Given a path $e: (-b, b) \to S$ on a surface $S$ in 3-space, when is there a
>   geodesic path $c : (-g, g) \to S$ whose image is the same as that of
>   $e$?

Assuming that $e$ is nondegenerate (i.e., that $\|e'(t)\| > 0$ for all $t$), you can always reparameterize $e$ by a unit-speed path $f$ (the so-called "arc-length" parameterization), although writing out a formula for this path may not be feasible in elementary terms. And then you can ask what the two conditions 
on $f$ say about $e$. The first -- that $f$ is constant speed -- says nothing about $e$ except that it's nondegenerate. The second --- surface- and curve-normal point in the same direction --- turns out to say that for every $t$, the vector $e''(t)$ lies in the span of $e'(t)$ and $n(e(t))$. Informally, the acceleration of of $e$ is either

1. along the curve, a result of the parameterization speeding up or slowing down, or
2. perpendicular to the underlying **surface**,

or perhaps a combination of the two.

Comment: Dosnt the derivative of the tanget belong to the plane while the normal to the plane dosnt? In the first example

Comment: Yes...that's right. All I said was that the derivative of the tangent and the normal to the surface lie in different directions. In a more general surface, the derivative of the tangent might lie outside the surface (think of a circular curve going around a cylinder, or a spiral "climbing" the cylinder. When the surface is a plane, the tangent-deriv, will ALWAYS lie in the plane...which means the only way for it to be parallel to the plane normal is for it to be ZERO, so the tangent vector is constant, i.e., the path parameterizes a straight line of constant speed, which is what you'd hope.